# Performing work in custom delegate blocks UI -- why?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, delegates

I wrote a custom "JSON fetcher". From my view controller I call `[loader start];` and when `loader` is done, it runs the delegate method `[self.delegate doneLoading];`.

This all works, however the UI is blocked -- can't move anything -- until the loader is done. I thought that if I did the loading over my own delegate method, this wouldn't happen. What am I missing here? Is there some extra method I need to call?

```
- (void)getBandArray
{
    if (![self localBandVersion] || [self remoteBandVersion] > [self localBandVersion] || !CACHING) {
        NSLog(@"Band array loaded remotely.");
    [self startLoadingBands];
}else{
    NSLog(@"Band array loaded from disk.");
    [self loadBandsFromDisk];

    }
}
```

startLoadingBands starts the NSURLConnection, loadBandsFromDisk looks like this:

```
- (void)loadBandsFromDisk
{
    NSData *dataFromDisk = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[self fileStringForTag:JNKBandTag]];
if (dataFromDisk) {
    NSLog(@"Found band cache on disk...");

    NSString *strToParse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataFromDisk encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    SBJsonParser *jsonObject = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    NSError *jsonError;
    NSArray *parsedResult = [jsonObject objectWithString:strToParse error:&jsonError];
    [strToParse release];
    [jsonObject release];

    if (parsedResult && [parsedResult count] > 0) {
        NSLog(@"Parsed bands, handing over to delegate...");

        NSMutableArray *bandArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSDictionary *bandDict in parsedResult) {
            [bandArray addObject:[JNKBand bandWithDictionary:bandDict]];
        } 

        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(bandArrayArrived:)]) {
            [self.delegate bandArrayArrived:bandArray];
        }
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Error parsing bands, calling delegate...");
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(bandArrayFailed)]) {
            [self.delegate bandArrayFailed];
        }
    }        
}else{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(bandArrayFailed)]) {
        [self.delegate bandArrayFailed];
    }
}
}
```

The weird thing is that once the connection is finished it also eventually calls loadFileFromDisk but this works smoothley...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is running on the main thread which is blocking everything else. You will have to do the loading in the background. Use `performSelectorInBackground:withObject` to do the loading in the background and if the delegate method is supposed to affect the UI, you should send the request back to the main thread.

Comment: I get a lot of "__NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): ... autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking" messages using your technique... Where do I need to put the NSAutoReleasePool to fix this...?

Comment: @JNK: you need to create a pool at the beginning of the method that's being performed in the background, and `drain` it at the end of that method. Also be careful with passing objects back to the main thread; you will need to be very sure that the object gets retained _before_ the memory gets released in the background. This is why `performSelectorOnMainThread:` has a `waitUntilDone:` parameter; it blocks the second thread if necessary to allow the main thread to manage the memory of the passed object.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is good, but you need to write code to put the work being done in `[loader start]` into a background thread. Right now the control flow just continues into `[loader start]` and executes whatever code you wrote there, calls your delegate, and returns to the next line of code after calling start.

Without knowing more about what you're doing I can't say exactly how to accomplish background threading, but taking a look at NSOperationQueue and the NSURLConnection asynchronous methods would be a good place to start.

Comment: It seems to me that the built-in asynchronous scheme that `NSURLConnection` and its delegate have may very well be why the OP is confused about delegate methods not blocking.

Comment: Yup. It occurred to me too that maybe JNK doesn't actually need the delegate pattern-- NSOperation + a completion block may work well enough and require less code. Not that delegates are a bad idea for this kind of situation, but usually the simpler solution is better.

Comment: @Marc Charbonneau: I am already using NSURLConnection, (this is working fine asynchronously). My Loader works like this: when "start loading" gets called it checks if a new version is available (if so it starts downloading with nsurlconnection) if not it loads the file from disk. The loading from disk part is what breaks the ui. Although the same "loadFromDisk" method gets called when the download is complete (because the file is saved to the disk). It only 'lags' if I call "loadFromDisk" directly...

Comment: In the end I want an easy way to get the information I need whether online or not, if a new version is available it downloads it and then calls the delegate, if not it's supposed to return the cached data...

Comment: In general, any IO operation (reading something from disk, loading a URL from the network) can potentially block your UI. It's better to push these operations off in a background thread. In Cocoa NSOperation is usually a good starting point for easy threading.

Comment: How would I need to call my "loadBandsFromDisk" method inside "getBandArray" using NSOperation?